# How to add two objects to database using one post request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I am still new at ASP.NET MVC. I'm trying to add two objects to two different tables via one JSON POST request.
Here's more explanation:

I have this CAR entity:

```
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int CarId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public double Price { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime Expiry { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public ICollection<Owner> Owners{ get; set; } = new List<Owner>();

    }
```

I made a DTO for my CAR class which will help me create Cars normally. This is it, called CarForCreationDTO:

```
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Price is a required field.")]
        public double Price{ get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Expiry is a required field.")]
        public DateTime Expiry { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Owners is a required field.")]
        public ICollection<OwnerDTO> Owners { get; set; } = new List<OwnerDTO>();
```

Here is the OwnerDTO:

```
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public int CarId { get; set; }
```

Now, when I post a request to add a Car, I need to provide a price, an expiry date and a list of owners.
So, normally, my JSON request should like this:

```
{
        "Price": "2020-03-28T00:00:00",
        "Expiry":  "2020-05-28T00:00:00",
        "Owners": [
            {
                 "Name":"Some Name",
                "DateOfBirth":"2001-03-28T00:00:00"
            }
        ]
}
```

In my CarController.cs, I did this to be able to add to the database both the Owner object and then the Car object :

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult CreateCar([FromBody] CarForCreationDTO car)
        {
            //Some validation ...

            var finalCar = _mapper.Map<Entities.Car>(car);

            foreach(var o in finalCar.Owners)
            {
                var finalOwner = _mapper.Map<Entities.Owner>(o);
                o.CarId= finalCar.CarId;
                _repository.AddOwner(finalOwner);
                _repository.Save();
            }


            _repository.AddCar(finalCar);

            _repository.Save();

            var createdCar = _mapper.Map<Entities.Car>(finalCar);

            return CreatedAtRoute("GetCar", new { id = createdCar.CarId},
                createdCar);
```

I am sadly getting a 500 Bad Request and I know it's from the "Owners" list but I don't know why that's happening. Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this because I am not finding any solutions to my problem.
Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks a lot,
Jane

Comment: check your server log why you get status 500

Comment: Which error did you get? Have you used `Include` (assuming that EF is used as ORM) for `Owners` list in repository?

Comment: also `o.CarId= finalCar.CarId;` should be `finalOwner.CarId= finalCar.CarId;` instead because the id missing in your mapped object?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I changed it. I am getting this error: AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: 'Error mapping types.' on this line of code: 
            `var finalCar = _mapper.Map<Entities.Car>(car);`

Comment: Did you try to look into exception details? It should say which members are not mapped ?

Comment: It is the "Owners" property as I have tried commenting out the Owners logic in my code and all worked fine.

Comment: Just for the record 500 corresponds to "Internal Server Error", not "Bad Request"(400).

Comment: Have you tried making your carid in DTO nullable?